# Creating values with loop in vba and storing them in a column in the worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to calculate velocity and acceleration, with the variable being the time t. I'd like to write these in vba, to make it faster, because later on I'll need velocity and acceleration for several other calculations combined with different logical conditions. I would like the results to be printed in the worksheet, to double check during calculation if the results are realistic.

example of how it should like more or less

```
t        vel          a

0.002   39        -777
0.004   38.6      -802
0.006   35        -500
0.008   33.4      -400
0.01    32.1      -12297.1
```

So I have tried a few different things based on comments:
This first code example works fine I think from the results, but I still can see any of the results in between > so main question: any chance I can change the commend to write to the worksheet without changing much else?

The second code example is an attempt to write everything into arrays: I do understand the principle I think, but here the main error seems to be that my variable t is not getting generated properly and therefore the formulas are not calculated: can't find the mistakes here and I would be grateful for some more help...

```
Kinematics Calculation

'Set t from 0 to 2 s with time step of 0.002s; Calculate Rot_vel until <= 0, 
'Find index t_2 when Rot_vel <= 0
t = 0
Do

t = t + 0.002

Rot_vel = -10356# * t ^ 6 + 24130# * t ^ 5 - 19002# * t ^ 4 + 4933# * t ^ 3 + 
362# * t ^ 2 - 213# * t + 39
    Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(1003, 2)) = Rot_vel

Loop Until Rot_vel <= 0


If Rot_vel <= 0 Then

t_2 = t

    If t_2 > 0 Then
       Debug.Print t_2
    End If
 End If

'Continue calculations for t 0 to t_2 with 0.002 steps
t = 0
Do

t = t + 0.002

    A_rot = -62136# * t ^ 5 + 120650# * t ^ 4 - 76008# * t ^ 3 + 14797.8 * t 
 ^ 2 + 723.26 * t - 212.7                                                                                                    


    Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 3), Cells(1003, 3)).value = A_rot

    L = MoI * Rot_vel / 1000
    M = MoI * A_rot / 1000

    Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 8), Cells(1003, 8)).value = L
    Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 9), Cells(1003, 9)).value = M

    G = L / t_2
    Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 10), Cells(1003, 10)).value = G


 Loop Until t = t_2
```

Second version:

```
Kinematics Calculation

'Set t from 0 to 2 s with time step of 0.002s; Calculate Rot_vel until <= 0, 
'Find index t_2 when Rot_vel <= 0

Dim arrCalc As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

ReDim arrCalc(i To 1003, j To 13)

For i = LBound(arrCalc, 2) To UBound(arrCalc, 2)

t = 0
Do
t = t + 0.002

    arrCalc(i, 1) = t

    arrCalc(i, 2) = -10356# * t ^ 6 + 24130# * t ^ 5 - 19002# * t ^ 4 + 4933# 
  * t ^ 3 + 362# * t ^ 2 - 213# * t + 39                    'Rot_vel

Loop Until arrCalc(i, 2) < 0

Dim pos, val
val = 0
pos = Application.Match(val, arrCalc(i, 2), False)
pos = t_2


t = 0
Do
t = t + 0.002

    arrCalc(i, 3) = -62136# * t ^ 5 + 120650# * t ^ 4 - 76008# * t ^ 3 + 
    14797.8 * t ^ 2 + 723.26 * t - 212.7

    arrCalc(i, 8) = MoI * Rot_vel / 1000      'L                                                                                       


    arrCalc(i, 9) = MoI * A_rot / 1000    'M                                                                                        


    arrCalc(i, 10) = 1 / t_2 * L     'G                                                                                           


Loop Until t = t_2

Next i

With Worksheets("test")

    .Cells(2, "A") = 0
    .Cells(3, "A").Resize(UBound(arrCalc, 1), UBound(arrCalc, 2)) = Rot_vel
    .Cells(2, "A").Resize(UBound(arrCalc, 1) + 1, 1) = t
    '.Cells(3, "C").Resize(UBound(arrCalc, 1), UBound(arrCalc, 3)) = A_rot

End With
```

Comment: Well first dead giveaway would be that you're looping to infinity with no `Exit For` (break) condition. Endless loops are a no go. If anything, do an approximation. It's virtually impossible to create a perfect calculation in mathematical terms, because the perfect calculation would never actually steps (the most accurate one) - which is also the case with your code, so you should stop trying to break rules of arithmetic first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes you are right, the result is the same though whether I use 1003 for example (for the inital 2 s) or infinity. I tried infinity because I thought the defined 1003 is inducing an error.

Comment: Please post your desired output, simularly to how you described your current output. Is it literally just increasing time period `t` or anything else?

Comment: Can't seem to be able to make a table in these comments... Yes it is just the time step increase and the corresponding results I would like to see in the columns

Comment: Not sure why you have the `for` loop inside a `do` loop at the start, you can easily hit your targets keeping it in one single loop, and as mentioned, there is a risk of infinite looping because the internal `For` loop might skip past `t=2` and your `Do` loop will never exit - you could at least do `Loop until t > 2` so if it exceeds 2, it will end...

Comment: I have the For loop to define i from cell number 3 to 1003, to plot the t values in column 1. I don't know how to store the values within the Do Loop ..

Answer (score 1):

Your variables a_rot and rot_val don't look to me like arrays but normal variables. Therefore, only one value is stored in them and of course you get only one value as an output.

I see two options: 1) You write all of your values into an array and then copy the array to the sheet. 2) You write each calculation line by line to the sheet. Number 1) is much much faster.

A solution could look something like this:

```
ReDim Array (Lines, Columns)    
For each line
Array (line, Columns1) = Formula1
Array (line, Columns2) = Formula2
Array (line, Columns3) = Formula3         
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. Alright I see the point, but wouldn't I have to define t as an array as well, to be able to visualize the values? If I try that I can't define t = 0 to 2 anymore with the Do Loop , the mismatch error appears then ..

Comment: I thought about an array with 3 columns and as many lines as you need. You could then iterate through the column with two for loops. The outer one for the lines and the inner one for the columns with a different formula for each column. Maybe with so few formulas a second for loop is not even needed.

Comment: ok, thanks for the idea. Where do I have to pay attention to when completing formula1? Can I just write the formula like in octave or do I have to use some worksheet function or application around it? I get an error: subscript out of range when I tried ..

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know octave. What I meant is that you could just put your formula over there, like you already wrote them in your code example.

Comment: ok yes I tried your idea, the problem with the code now is that all values are empty and I guess it is due to the time variable not being calculated properly. so it just calculates the formuals and gives one result for each array, 0. Then, I don't manage to get past the array of G, because it thinks t_2 is 0, so division by zero gives an error.                                                                        And I still don't manage to paste the results into the columns and rows in the worksheet, where I was hoping to see the mistake happen, so to say...

Comment: Posting into a sheet from an array works like this: Worksheets("test").Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(1003, 2)).Value = Array // It is important to make sure that the range has the same size as the array.

Answer (score 1):

Build a 2-D array with times and calculations then dump the results back onto the worksheet.

Sequential time is very prone to [15 significant digit floating point errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel). These errors can be minimized with a form of datum dimensioning that creates all new entries relative to the original starting point instead of the previous value. The former method can have no error greater than a single calculation while the latter can compounding errors by carrying them into the next calculation.

```
Sub kinematicsCalculation()
    Dim t As Double, start As Double, i As Long, arr As Variant

    start = TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)   'start at 0 second mark
    ReDim arr(1 To 1000, 1 To 2)

    For i = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        arr(i, 1) = start + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2 * i) / 1000
        'cannot attempt velocity calc without Rot_vel_i
        arr(i, 2) = "<velocity calculation here>"
    Next i

    With Worksheets("sheet")
        .Cells(2, "B") = start
        .Cells(3, "B").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
        .Cells(2, "B").Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, 1).NumberFormat = "[hh]:mm:ss.000"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This sounds really interesting. I have just tried, the time steps work fine now, but not the velocity calculation yet. It just decreases incrementally by 0.0001, from 39 = rot_vel_i, but doesn't get calculated. I guess I am writing the formula wrongly when in an array?  How do I include the variable t? I have tried by using arr(i,1) instead of t in the formula in the original post, but it doesn't work? do I have to define the time array again as something different, range maybe, to do the calculation?

Comment: Yes, t is arr(i, 1). However, I'm using real time where a second is actually 0.00001157407407, not 1.

Comment: Ok! I am still at a loss tough how I'll get my result for every 0.002 seconds. Can I decouple it from actually being time, just a variable from 0 to 2, with 0.002 step to avoid all the significant digit floating points?

Comment: have thought more about it, maybe it is not the time step the problem but the formula itself? With the several "power of" arr(i,1) should be double and the results will be double as well, no? Is that the problem? because rot_vel is decreasing linearly with your code so far, and not in a polynomial fashion as it technically should according to the formula ..